# Channel network from DEM of a river has unusual linear lines

Tags: qgis, saga, watershed, flow-direction

So I needed to obtain channel network, basins, flow direction, etc. I downloaded aster_DEM from usgs, clipped it to an extent, warped it to UTM projection, then filled the sinks using Wang and Liu saga tool. The output consists of linear lines at the watershed basin but everywhere else it looks normal. I tried to enlarge the extent but the output is the same. Is this normal?

I am using SAGA 7.8.2 in QGIS 3.22.14
River: Narayani
UTM zone EPSG 32645 WGS84/UTM zone 45N

[image: Before enlarged extent]

[image: After Enlarged extent]

Comment: It looks like the area that produces the very straight sections has a constant value i.e. you've over-filled the DEM, as such the valleys are lakes. According to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375569/why-no-need-for-fill-sinks-when-using-r-watershed-in-grass-qgis you do not need to fill the sinks before you create a watershed

Comment: I tried this but the stream order is all over the place so I guess DEM filling has to be done. I used SAGA tool for the task, maybe it is only the GRASS tool that doesn't require you to fill the sinks.

Comment: There might be a problem with the quality of the DEM. You could also try using Breach Depressions (Whitebox Tools) rather than Fill Sinks